# Linear algebra question on rank and null space

Tags: linear-algebra

This is an exercise from *linear algebra and optimization by Gill*, I do exercises to be prepared for my final exam and these are not homework questions!

> **Exercise $\mathbf{6.1.}\,$** Consider the following matrix $A$ and vector $b$:
>   $$
> A=\begin{pmatrix}
> 2 & 4 \\
> 1 & 2  \\
> 1 & 2   \\
> \end{pmatrix},\quad 
> b=\begin{pmatrix}
> 3  \\
> 2   \\
> 1    \\
> \end{pmatrix}.
> $$
>   $\textbf{(a)}$ What is the rank of $A$? Give a general form for any vector in the range of $A$.
>
> $\textbf{(b)}$ Show that the dimension of the null space of $A^T$ is two, and display two linearly independent vectors $z_1$ and $z_2$ in $\operatorname{null}(A^T)$. Give a general form for every vector in $\operatorname{null}(A^T)$.
>
> $\textbf{(c)}$ Find the vectors $b_R\in\operatorname{range}(A)$ and $b_N\in\operatorname{range}(A^T)$ such that $b=b_R+b_N$.
>
> $\textbf{(d)}$ Give the *general* form of $b_A$ such that $b_R=Ab_A$. (Hint: consider all vectors $q$ such that $Aq=0$.)

For part (a), I think $rank(A)=1$ since all the columns are linear combination of each other. As for a general form for any vector in the range of $A$, when I write $Ax=b$ I get an over-determined system:

$$2x_1+4x_2=3$$
$$x_1+2x_2=2$$ 
$$x_1+2x_2=1$$

So I'm not sure about the general form.

As for part (b), since the rank is two, dimension of $N(A^T)$ must be $3-1=1$, right?

And no idea about the rest. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If you know row reduction and properties of row reduced matrix then apply. It will be easier to get all answer together.

Comment: Your solution to (a) is correct. For (b) note that if the dimension of the null space is two and you already found two linearly independent vectors in the null space, those form a base. Now that directly gives you a general form of all null vectors.

Comment: For (c) note that $\text{null}(A^T)$ are exactly the vectors that are not in the image of $A$ (aka $\text{range}(A)$). The image of $A$ gets spanned by $(2,1,1)$ thus you can write $b$ as $\alpha z_1+\beta z_2 + \gamma (2,1,1)$. where $z_1,z_2$ are from (b).

Comment: @Listing: Thank you, that helped to understand the problem.

Comment: Thank you for the edit @Aðøbe.

Comment: You're welcome! :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you do row reduction, you find
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
2 & 4 \\
1 & 2 \\
1 & 2
\end{pmatrix}
\to
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 2 \\
0 & 0 \\
0 & 0
\end{pmatrix}
$$
which means that the first column is a basis for the column space of $A$ (which is better terminology than “range of $A$”, in my opinion). So the general form of the vectors in the column space of $A$ is
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
2a \\
a \\
a
\end{pmatrix},\quad \text{$a$ any scalar}
$$

By the rank nullity theorem, the null space of $A$ has dimension $1$; the equation defining it is
$$
x_1+2x_2=0
$$
so a basis for it is the single vector
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
-2 \\
1
\end{pmatrix}
$$

The null space of $A^T$ has indeed dimension $2$; the row reduction on $A^T$ is
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
2 & 1 & 1 \\
4 & 2 & 2
\end{pmatrix}
\to
\begin{pmatrix}
2 & 1 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 0
\end{pmatrix}
$$
so the equation defining the null space is $2x_1+x_2+x_3=0$ and a basis for it is
$$
\left\{
\begin{pmatrix}
-1 \\ 2 \\ 0
\end{pmatrix}
\,,
\begin{pmatrix}
-1 \\ 0 \\ 2
\end{pmatrix}
\right\}
$$
Writing $b=b_R+b_N$ should now be easy: the system to solve is
$$
\left(\begin{array}{ccc|c}
2 & -1 & -1 & 3 \\
1 & 2 & 0 & 2 \\
1 & 0 & 2 & 1
\end{array}\right)
$$
but you can as well find the orthogonal projection of $b$ on the column space of $A$:
$$
b_R=
\frac{(2\ 1\ 1)\begin{pmatrix}3\\2\\1\end{pmatrix}}
     {(2\ 1\ 1)\begin{pmatrix}2\\1\\1\end{pmatrix}}
\begin{pmatrix}2\\1\\1\end{pmatrix}
=\frac{9}{6}\begin{pmatrix}2\\1\\1\end{pmatrix}
=\begin{pmatrix}3\\3/2\\3/2\end{pmatrix}
$$
and $b_N=b-b_R$.

With this last idea it's easy to solve the last point.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer. Where did you use the fact that the first column is a basis for the column space (because it has leading $1$, right?)? And how did you come up with that general form, $\begin{pmatrix}
2a \\
a \\
a
\end{pmatrix}$?

Comment: @Gigili I used it for the last part, when computing $b_R$ with the orthogonal projection. Since the first column is a basis for the column space, every vector in the column space is that vector times a scalar.

Comment: Ah, right! I was thinking of $\begin{pmatrix}
1 \\
0 \\
0
\end{pmatrix}$ as the first column but it's the first column in REF. Thanks, it's clear now.

Comment: Sorry, but I still don't get the last part about $b$. Where did that system come from? Did you multiply the basis by $-1$? Then what's the first row? How did you calculate $b_R$?

Comment: @Gigili It's a common error, I find it all the time in students' papers. `;-)` The first non zero column in REF is *always* that one! It can't be in the column space of every matrix, can it?

Comment: Umm, no I don't understand where did you get your last system from! I see $b$ is the last column and the other columns are some multiplication of what you calculated, the basis of column space of and null space. Could you clarify? This is my last question, I promise!

Comment: @Gigili Time for exams now; I'll be back later.

Comment: I wouldn't need the answer by that time, I neededit for my final exam.

Comment: @Gigili The construction of a basis for the null space is standard: you reduce the matrix and then write the equations with the nonfree variables in terms of the free ones; then you give one free variable the value $1$ (or any nonzero value) and $0$ to the others, in all possible ways, so as to get the same number of vectors as the number of free variables, which is the dimension of the null space.

Comment: I asked about the system you wrote right after $b=b_R+b_N$, I understand the rest of it.

Comment: @Gigili Write $b$ as a linear combination of the generator of the column space of $A$ and of the generators of the null space of $A^T$.